# GoRouter - Entering the url in the address bar doesn't only create the related page

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-routes, flutter-go-router

I'm writing a web flutter application with [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router).

Below is a code sample to illustrate how it is architectured (you can also check out [this repo](https://github.com/ValentinVignal/flutter_app_stable/tree/go-router/non-opaque-route)).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      redirect: (_) => '/persons',
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/persons',
      builder: (_, __) => const PersonsScreen(),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: ':id',
          pageBuilder: (_, __) => const DrawerPage(
            child: PersonScreen(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
      routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
    );
  }
}

class PersonsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PersonsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('Persons'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => GoRouter.of(context).push('/persons/1'),
              child: const Text('Push'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PersonScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PersonScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('Person'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: GoRouter.of(context).pop,
              child: const Text('Pop'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawerPage extends Page {
  const DrawerPage({
    required this.child,
  });

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Route createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return _DrawerPageRoute(
      settings: this,
    );
  }
}

class _DrawerPageRoute extends TransitionRoute {
  _DrawerPageRoute({
    required DrawerPage settings,
  }) : super(
          settings: settings,
        );
  @override
  Iterable<OverlayEntry> createOverlayEntries() {
    return [
      OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) {
          return Row(
            children: [
              const Spacer(flex: 2),
              Expanded(
                  child: SlideTransition(
                position: animation!.drive(
                  Tween(
                    begin: const Offset(1, 0),
                    end: const Offset(0, 0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: (settings as DrawerPage).child,
              )),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 200);
}
```

It has 2 pages:

1. `/persons`
2. `/persons/:id`

`/persons` is just a grey screen:

[image: Persons screen]

When I click on *"Push"*, it pushed `/persons/1` which is a transparent route that takes a 3 of the screen:

[image: Person screen]

This works well and I can still see the previous screen related to `/persons` behind the `DrawerPage`.
And when I click on *"Pop"*, it does remove the purple screen (as it should).

---

But what I don't understand is when I paste myself the URL in the browser's address bar (for example `/persons/3`), it also ends up with the purple page that takes 1/3 of the screen (this is fine), but for some reason, the grey screen (linked to `/persons`) is behind and I can pop to go to the previous page (`/persons`) when I click on *"Pop"*.

How and why is this page built?
How does flutter/GoRouter decide that when going to `/persons/:id` it should insert `persons/` as the first page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works.

According to the documentation (https://gorouter.dev/sub-routes):

*`go_router will match the routes all the way down the tree of sub-routes to build up a stack of pages`*

The route `/persons/id` includes the screen `/persons` in the stack and that is why it is shown.

If you want a screen showing `/persons/id` without the stack, you could define a different route where `/persons/id` is the root. Like:

```
final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      redirect: (_) => '/persons',
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/persons',
      builder: (_, __) => const PersonsScreen(),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: ':id',
          pageBuilder: (_, __) => const DrawerPage(
            child: PersonScreen(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/person/:id',
      pageBuilder: (_, __) => const DrawerPage(
        child: PersonScreen(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```